# CASE in SQL Server WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need query like below which contains CASE in where clause

```
 DECLARE @BillBack INT
 SET @BillBack=1
       
 SELECT 
     coloumn1, coloumn2, coloumn3, [Project_id] 
 FROM 
     [Purchase_Details]
 WHERE 
     (CASE WHEN @BillBack = 0  
             THEN [Project_id] = 0
           WHEN @BillBack = 1   
             THEN [Project_id] != 0 
      END  
      OR [Project_id] IN (1, 2, 3)
     )
```

Above query gives error, is it possible to do it in a different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the positioning of your `CASE ... WHEN`, it appears you are trying to do the following:

```
 SELECT colomn1, column2, column3, [Project_id] 
 FROM [Purchase_Details]
 WHERE 
     [Project_id]  IN (1,2,3)
     OR ((@BillBack = 0 AND [Project_id] = 0)
         OR (@BillBack = 1 AND [Project_id] <> 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
 WHERE ((@BillBack = 0 AND      [Project_id] = 0) OR (@BillBack = 1 AND [Project_id] !=0)) OR [Project_id] IN (1, 2, 3)
```

It means that if BillBack is zero the project_id has to be 0 or if the BillBack is 1 project_id has to be differente from zero, if both are false the project_id needs to be 1, 2 or 3.

Assuming that Project_id is always 0 or a positive number, you can also try:

```
 WHERE @BillBack <= [Project_id] OR [Project_id] IN (1, 2, 3)
```

It means that if BillBack is 0 the statement is true only if project_id is also 0. And if BillBack is 1 the statement is true if the project_id is greater than 0. Or if project_id in (1, 2, 3)

Or try some similar boolean logic that's equivalent to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your case result needs to be a comparison in the where clause..
try

```
DECLARE @INT INT = 1;
SELECT COL1, COL2
FROM TABLE
WHERE (COL2 = (CASE WHEN @INT = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END))
OR COL1 IN (1,2,3);
```